# How to structure a database where a record can be a child of a parent or a grand parent record

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, normalization

I have these concepts for a database application: `Session`, `Subsession` and `File`

- A session can have multiple files
- A session can have multiple subsessions
- A subsession can have multiple files
- A session and subsession are completely different concepts, they don't have much in common so they cannot be merged into one table.

I am trying to decide between 2 alternative schemas or maybe a better schema that I couldn't think of.

The first schema I designed with 3 tables is like this:

---

### `Sessions` Table

- SessionID: Primary key
- SessionField1
- SessionField2
- ...

### `Subsessions` Table

- SubsessionID : Primary key
- SessionID
- SubsessionField1
- SubsessionField2
- ...

Foreign key constraint: SessionID => Sessions.SessionID

### `Files` Table

- FileID: Primary key
- SessionID: Nullable
- SubsessionID: Nullable
- FileName: VARCHAR
- CreationDate: DateTime

Foreign key constraint: SessionID => Sessions.SessionID

Foreign key constraint: SubsessionID => Subsessions.SubsessionID

---

This table structure has the following disadvantage:

If a file belongs to a subsession, then should I still fill in the SessionID field in Files table? It would be redundant since SessionID information is already kept in the Subsession. But if I don't fill it in, then I need to make sure either SessionID or SubsessionID is filled in, but not both of them.

So I came up with an alternative table structure, this time with 4 tables:

---

### `Sessions` Table

- SessionID: Primary key
- SessionField1
- SessionField2
- ...

### `Subsessions` Table

- SubsessionID : Primary key
- SessionID
- SubsessionField1
- SubsessionField2
- ...

Foreign key constraint: SessionID => Sessions.SessionID

### `SessionFiles` Table

- FileID: Primary key
- SessionID: Nullable
- FileName: VARCHAR
- CreationDate: DateTime
  Foreign key constraint: SessionID => Sessions.SessionID

### `SubsessionFiles` Table

- FileID: Primary key
- SubsessionID: Nullable
- FileName: VARCHAR
- CreationDate: DateTime

Foreign key constraint: SessionID => Sessions.SessionID

---

And the disadvantage of this schema is that if I decide to change the schema of Files, I need to change 2 tables, so I need to keep them in sync since they basically represent the same object, just with different owners (session or subsession).

Which schema is a better practice in your opinion? Or is there a better schema design for these types of situations?

Comment: Can a File be associated with only a single Session or a single SubSession, or is there a many-to-many relation possible?

Comment: A file can be associated to only one Session or one Subsession.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If files can be associated either with sessions or subsessions, you should consider using separate association tables for that.

## `Session` table

- Id
- ...

## `SubSession` table

- Id
- Session -> references Sessions.Id
- ...

## `Files` table

- Id
- FileName
- ...

## `SessionFiles` table

- Session -> references Session.Id
- File -> references Files.Id

## `SubSessionFiles` table

- SubSession -> references SubSessions.Id
- File -> references Files.Id

If you want to enforce the unique ownership of files, you'll want a custom constraint for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed sessions and subsessions have more properties in common than just the property of being a container for files, I would avoid to have two different tables `Session` and `Subsession`. Just give `Session` a nullable foreign key field `ParentSessionID`. Where this field is `NULL`, the session is a "normal" one, where it is filled, the session is a subsession.

Now you `Files` only needs a `SessionID` field.

Comment: Sorry I should have made clear in the question that Session and Subsession are completely different concepts with their own fields. I will edit my question to reflect that. Still thank you for your answer, that is indeed a good solution when session and subsession represent the same thing.

Comment: @CanolGökel: even if session and subsession require different fields, I guess they also have some commonalites? Then make 3 tables: MainSession, Subsession, and Session, where `Session` bundles the commonalities of MainSession and Subsession, and records have a 1:1 relationship from MainSession to Session as well as from Subsession to Session.

Comment: Sessions and subsessions unfortunately have almost entirely different fields.

Comment: @CanolGökel: then the common "Session" table will be small, but nevertheless solving you problem.